# WPF: How works HorizontalAlignment and HorizontalContentAlignment in parent and child control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface

I am trying to understand how `HorizontalAlignment` and `HorizontalContentAlignment` will work with regard to parent control.

For example, here is simple code:

```
<StatusBar VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="600" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"  HorizontalAlignment="Left">
  <Label Margin="5">StatusBar</Label>
</StatusBar>
```

I suppose that the Label will appear at the right side of the StatusBar, because in MCTS 70-511 book I found that HorizontalContantAlignment *"Gets or sets the horizontal alignment of the control’s content."* Isn't the Label is a content in my case? If it is not, so what is?

I have tried to add `HorizontalAlignment="Right"` to my Label but it made no changes.

Moreover, what will happen if my parent control has `HorizontalContentAligment="Left"` and the content of it will has `HorizontalContentAligment="Right"`? Child's property will "cover" the one from parent?

Answer (score 0):

`HorizontalAlignment="Right"` - This will change the Alignment for the Control. 
`HorizontalContentAligment="Left"` - This Will change the Alignment for the Content based on its parent.

In your code, `StatusBar` will be set to Left alignment based on its parent.

`Label` will be set to Right based on the `StatusBar`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa970569(v=vs.100).aspx

With the reference of the above like, `StatusBar` wasnt use the `HorizontalContentAligment` Property in its Control Template, so it will not reflect in your Code.

Comment: Label is stil on the Left now with this code sample. Somehow it is not using HorizontalContentAligment="Right" from StatusBar. If I write HorizontalAligment="Right"  on the Label it will not move to Right either.

Comment: It is just an example of style for StatusBar. Why do you think that it works exactly the same way when I am using default StatusBar? Moreover, why the alignmet applied to Label make no change to appearance?

Comment: So your using your own Style for StatusBar and the HorizontalContentAligment property is Templated Bound?

Comment: No, I am not. I just understood the line "The following example shows how to define a ControlTemplate for the StatusBar control." as it is just an example of how it could work for default StatusBar.